# Where does the Y.M.C.A dance comes from?

Tags: music-video, dancing

Looking at the [Village People's *Y.M.C.A.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS9OO0S5w2k) music video, I don't see the well known dance with dancers shaping the letters with their arms... when comes the chorus, they just clap their hands above their heads.

[image: ymca]

In most of dancing hits (*The Twist*, *La Macarena*), people just look at how dancers perform in the music video to learn the dance craze.

I wonder how does the dance was invented, and how does it spread in a way that thousands of people will dance it in a live show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Citing a [spin.com](https://www.spin.com/2008/05/ymca-oral-history/) interview of [Randy Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randy_Jones_(singer)) and [David Hodo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hodo) (respectively the cowboy and construction worker of the song):

> ***Jones***: We were flying up from South America for the show, and we
>   worked on the choreography on the airplane — handclaps, turning,
>   marching in place…stuff like that. Well, the audience at this
>   particular taping was a bunch of kids bused in from a cheerleader
>   camp. The first time we got to the chorus, we were clapping our hands
>   above our heads. And **the kids thought it looked like we were making a
>   Y. So they automatically did the letters**. We saw this and started
>   doing letters with them. It was purely audience-generated, which is
>   probably why it’s still so popular. And that’s great for me, because
>   it keeps the checks coming in every six months.
>
> ***Hodo***: When I saw the movements, I thought, “Wow, that is so stupid.”
>   Then everyone in America started doing it, and I thought, “Wow, that
>   is so brilliant.” It took on a life of its own. The next thing we
>   know, Hideki Saijo has the No. 1 hit in Japan with his version of
>   “Y.M.C.A.” And we hit No. 2 [in the U.S.]. That’s how it always works.
>   **Saijo claimed to have invented the dance**, so as soon as we got to
>   Japan, we straightened him out.